# Create table using nodejs Dynamodb?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I want to create a table and want to create 6-7 columns/attributes using Dynamodb(NodeJs). I have created a table but I am not able to add more than 2 attributes.I am new to this platform, can anyone help me to create multiple attributes in one table.

Answer (score 6):

On DynamoDB, you must define only the `Hash Key` and optionally a `Sort Key` for your table. The rest of the attributes don't have to be defined! You can push whatever data you want.

Check out the example below, based on [the official docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html).

I'm creating a table `Movies` with Hash: `Year` and Sort: `Title`. 
Then I'm creating a movie with more attributes:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});

var client = new AWS.DynamoDB();
var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var tableName = "Movies";

var params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    KeySchema: [
        { AttributeName: "year", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "title", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        { AttributeName: "year", AttributeType: "N" },
        { AttributeName: "title", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
};

client.createTable(params, function(tableErr, tableData) {
    if (tableErr) {
        console.error("Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(tableErr, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Created table successfully!");
    }

    // Adding Batman movie to our collection
    var params = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Item: {
            "year": 2005,
            "title": "Batman Begins",
            "info": {
                "plot": "A young Bruce Wayne (Christian Bale) travels to the Far East.",
                "rating": 0
            }
        }
    };

    console.log("Adding a new item...");
    documentClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        } else {
            console.log("Added item successfully!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: code works fine but it throwing error in put -  create table Error ResourceInUseException: Attempt to change a resource which is still in use: Table is being created

Answer (score 3):

In dynamoDB, attributes will created automatically when you add an Item to the db.

While creating a table, we only specify the primary key and an optional sort key.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of creating a table on DynamoDB using nodejs AWS-SDK

```js
// Imports
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

AWS.config.update({ region: 'eu-west-3' });

// Declare local variables
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB();

createTable('your table name')
.then(data => console.log(data))

function createTable (tableName) {
  const params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    AttributeDefinitions: [
      // required attributes to be used as keys
      {
        AttributeName: 'id',
        AttributeType: 'N'
      }
    ],
    KeySchema: [
      {
        AttributeName: 'id',
        KeyType: 'HASH'
      }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
      ReadCapacityUnits: 5, // Eventually Consistent Model
      WriteCapacityUnits: 5
    }
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dynamo.createTable(params, (err, data) => {
      if(err) reject(err);
      else resolve(data);
    })
  })
}
```