# Import JSON Data in table (DynamoDB, nodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to import data from my JSON file into DynamoDB with this code:

```js
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var fs = require('fs');

AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-west-2",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

console.log("Importing Pays into DynamoDB. Please wait.");

var allPays = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('paysdata.JSON', 'utf8'));
allPays.forEach(function(pays) {
    var params = {
        TableName: "Pays",
        Item: {
            "region":  pays.region,
            "name": pays.name,
            "name.common": pays.name.common,
            "languages":  pays.languages,
            "area": pays.area
        }
    };

    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
           console.error("Unable to add Pays", pays.name.common, ". Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       } else {
           console.log("PutItem succeeded:", pays.name.common);
       }
    });
});
```

But I still get this error
[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoHck.png)
Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this problem? I tried to follow the same steps on the site:
[Create table using nodejs Dynamodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123775/create-table-using-nodejs-dynamodb)

But it does not work.

My CreateTable.js

```js
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var params = {
    TableName : "Pays",
    KeySchema: [       
        { AttributeName: "region", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "name", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [       
        { AttributeName: "region", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "name", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {       
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10, 
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
};

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Some data :

```js
[
    {
        "name": {
            "common": "Aruba",
            "official": "Aruba",
            "native": {
                "nld": {
                    "official": "Aruba",
                    "common": "Aruba"
                },
                "pap": {
                    "official": "Aruba",
                    "common": "Aruba"
                }
            }
        },
        "translations": {
            "ces": {
                "official": "Aruba",
                "common": "Aruba"
            },
            "deu": {
                "official": "Aruba",
                "common": "Aruba"
            },
            "jpn": {
                "official": "\u30a2\u30eb\u30d0",
                "common": "\u30a2\u30eb\u30d0"
            },
            "kor": {
                "official": "\uc544\ub8e8\ubc14",
                "common": "\uc544\ub8e8\ubc14"
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        "name": {
            "common": "Aruba",
            "official": "Aruba",
            "native": {
                "nld": {
                    "official": "Aruba",
                    "common": "Aruba"
                },
                "pap": {
                    "official": "Aruba",
                    "common": "Aruba"
                }
            }
        }
```

`name` is an object so you cannot `pays.name` as the value for `name`, since it is of "String" datatype.

To fix the problem, you can change the table definition to:

```
var params = {
    TableName : "Pays",
    KeySchema: [       
        { AttributeName: "region", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "name.common", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [       
        { AttributeName: "region", AttributeType: "S" },
        { AttributeName: "name.common", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {       
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10, 
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
};
```

Comment: 0


I tried to add the item "name" but i have this result :

Unable to add Pays Zimbabwe . Error JSON: { "message": "Invalid attribute value type", "code": "ValidationException", "time": "2022-01-15T12:31:39.062Z", "requestId": "7b5937f7-b52d-4f5b-8f6a-9792811a231f", "statusCode": 400, "retryable": false, "retryDelay": 23.159447753247807

Comment: What is the data type of `pays.name.common` and `pays.region`? It needs to be a String for both because you have specified an attribute type of "S" in the table definition.

Comment: I edited my post and copied some data

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your edits